# Streaming video over HTTP

Tags: java-me, video-streaming

I want to stream video in j2me using Http URL. I came across the [Nokia Developer forum](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/implementation-notes/jsr-135-mobile-media-api/series-40-class-and-interface-description/streaming.html). I have tried the two possibilities but it isn't working.I want to stream video using HTTP protocol. Is it possible to do so and how it can be achieved?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

When you open a media stream in Java ME it is usually buffered by Media API before rendering. Some devices, though, might play the stream as expected, but this is not the standard.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) is an industry wide standard where the client receives streaming audio/video from a standard HTTPD server where you have parked your media into a HLS friendly format.  Apple pushes this although as a standard there are tools available to convert your media into HLS on the server side.  Its independent of language and very efficient/flexible with respect to minimizing bandwidth requirements.